# jquery assign value on page load

Tags: jquery, textbox, assign

This is my second day with Jquery and I have a dropdown-list **each time a user selects an option on that list it is shown on a textbox using the change method** how can i use Jquery so that when the **page first loads the first element on that dropdownlist shows in the textbox?**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $('#textboxx')= $('#dropdown'); // this line doesn't work how can i make it 
        $(function () { 
            $('#dropdownn').change(function () {
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                $('#textboxx').val(selectedValue);
            });
        });

</script>
```

The code below started with the $function() works correctly but as I said im having trouble binding the dropdownlist value to the textbox when the page is first loaded.

Comment: Did you search before asking?

Comment: if it's your 2nd day with jQuery, don't start forgetting JS! ;) you can freely use: `this.value;`

Comment: Yes I did thats how I found the .change() but I will continue to learn as this is only my 2nd day today and all of this seems foreign at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the selected value of select to textbox on document.ready.

Change

```
$('#textboxx')= $('#dropdown');
```

To

```
$('#textboxx').val($('#dropdown').val());
```

And put in **document.ready**, You code would be

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () { 
            $('#textboxx').val($('#dropdown').val());
            $('#dropdownn').change(function () {
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                $('#textboxx').val(selectedValue);
            });
        });

</script>
```